# Hibernate 5.2.9.Final terminate

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate

После выполнения метода main программа не завершается.

Много гуглил, но все пишут только про `sessionFactory.close();`

Во-первых,я не создаю сессию вручную в принципе. Для общения с БД, я делаю получаю `EntityManager`:

```
EntityManager manager = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("COLIBRI")
        .createEntityManager();
```

А затем использую его, например так:

```
public Costumer get(long id) {
    return manager.find(Costumer.class, id);
}
```

Вызов `manager.close();`не помогает.

Вызов `((Session)costumerService.manager.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().close();` тоже не помогает, хотя в логах появляется:

```
апр 04, 2017 6:27:42 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop 
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:hsqldb:file:testdb]
```

Comment: а это `createEntityManagerFactory("COLIBRI")` как называется, если не создаю сессию вручную?

Comment: @Sergey ну сори, не правильно выразился. Не создаю сессию в явном виде. Понятное дело, что она создаётся.